# Why does reassigning to the function name inside the function body change its behavior?

Tags: javascript, scope

I came across this function when reverse engineering some JavaScript:

```js
function fun1() {
    const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
    fun1 = function () {
        return arr;
    };
    return fun1();
}
```

**It looks redundant to me**. The code seems to :

1. Declare an array `arr`.
2. Redefine the function inside itself to make it return `arr`.
3. Return the result of the function itself with `return fun1()`, which is now redefined to return `arr`, so this seems to return `arr`.

Therefore, I rewrote the function to eliminate all the redundant code to :

```js
function fun2() {
    const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
    return arr;
}
```

However, **I was surprised to see the behavior of these two functions is completely different**.

`fun1()` seems to be returning a reference to `arr` while `fun2()` seems to be returning a copy of `arr`.

Here is a runnable Minimal Reproducible Example to illustrate the difference :

```js
// This function is redefined inside itself to return arr
function fun1() {
  const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
  fun1 = function() {
    return arr;
  };
  return fun1();
}

// Why not return arr directly?
function fun2() {
  const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
  return arr;
}

// But the result is different...
let test_fun_1 = fun1();

test_fun_1.pop();

test_fun_1 = fun1();

console.log("Logging test_fun_1");

console.log(test_fun_1); // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

let test_fun_2 = fun2();

test_fun_2.pop();

test_fun_2 = fun2();

console.log("Logging test_fun_2");

console.log(test_fun_2); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

// What is this magic?
```

*Looks like magic happened here...*

**What is the difference between `fun1()` and `fun2()` ?**

Comment: Your code changes how it works... They are not equivalent because one uses the same array every time you call it and yours creates a new array every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `fun1()` function **redefines** the (relatively) global `fun1` symbol when it is first called. It changes the original to be that local inner function, which closes over the array. Thus there is only one array involved, the one created the first time `fun1()` is called.

Your `fun2()`, on the other hand, creates a brand new array each time it is called.

If you change `fun1()` so that the inner function is assigned to a *locally declared* `fun1` variable, it will work the same as `fun2()`.

Comment: Also I *really* hope that code is not in something actually in production, because it's a weird thing to do.

Comment: It is not really weird thing to do, but there are better patterns to do the same thing.

Comment: @epascarello yea making a function involve a closure is fine, it's the reassignment part that I feel is a little fishy.